# Passar parâmetros jquery para Url.Action ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou com dificuldades de montar uma URL com parâmetros.

Até então consegui usando o `@Url.Action`, mas o segundo parâmetro `dataPesquisa` está indo nulo.

Imagino eu que quando o parâmetro passado diretamente para o `@Url.Action` o C# deve realizar alguma conversão e no caso estou usando o `replace` para conseguir dar valores aos parâmetros.

Obs.: já verifiquei a variável `data` e ela está vindo com valor, só está indo nulo quando executa minha Action.

Modo que fiz:

```
var conta = $('#selectContaCorrente').val();
dataParaPesquisa = dataFormatada(dataPesquisa.val());                

var url = '@Url.Action("ExtratoPrint", "Extrato", new { contaCorrente = "paramContaCorrente", dataPesquisa = "paramDataPesquisa" })';

url = url.replace('paramContaCorrente', conta);
url = url.replace('paramDataPesquisa', dataPesquisa.val());

window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Valor da variável `url`: `/Extrato/ExtratoPrint?contaCorrente=3cb012d1-6ceb-436f-8a0f-22c713703804&amp;dataPesquisa=31/12/2009`

Action

```
public ActionResult ExtratoPrint(string contaCorrente, string dataPesquisa)
{
    ViewBag.ContaCorrente = contaCorrente;
    ViewBag.DataPesquisa = dataPesquisa;

    return View("ExtratoPrint");
}
```

Comment: "_o parâmetro dataPesquisa não está indo correto_". O que isso quer dizer?

Comment: Não, acabei de postar ai minha action

Comment: "Não" o quê? Eu perguntei o que isso quer dizer.

Comment: @LINQ, perdão, editei minha pergunta, acho que agora ficou mais claro.

Comment: Verifica se a variável `conta` tem algum valor ao chamar aquele script ali.

Comment: Verifiquei já, na minha action quando chamada a conta tem valor, mas a dataPesquisa vem nula, vou postar minha variavel url para você verificar como está ficando.

Comment: @LINQ, da uma olhada

Comment: Como é que você pretende usar uma data com barras se barra é justamente um "carácter reservado" em URL's?

Comment: Então, eu imaginei que seria esse o problema, mas a minha pergunta é, como passar parametros para o Url.Action com as variáveis do jquery, pois imagino eu que colocando o parametro data, o c# faz a conversão, entende ? tanto é que usei esses parâmetros em chamadas $.getJson e deu certo. Agora que estou usando com o ´Url.Action´ que estou tendo problema.

Comment: Não tem como você fazer isso. O Url.Action é código Razor, ele vai ser executado no **servidor**, o código JavaScript é executado no cliente. Você poder perceber isso abrindo o código da sua página, na parte do script não vai existir nenhum **Url.Action**, lá vai estar apenas o valor retornado por essa função. Isso porque ela já foi executada no servidor.

Comment: @LINQ, sabe se tem outro jeito que eu consiga chamar minha action e abrir ela em uma nova janela do jeito que estou fazendo ?

Comment: Tem um milhão de maneiras. Por que você apenas não muda o formato da data antes de fazer a requisição? Faça sua URL ficar assim `dataPesquisa=31-12-2009`.

Comment: Para qual formato por exemplo? poderia me dar um horizonte, rsrs.

Comment: Cara, eu escrevi o formato no comentário.

Comment: Coloquei da forma que disse e continua indo nulo o parâmetro :/

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi meu problema usando o @Html.Raw, da seguinte forma ficou:

```
var url = '@Html.Raw(@Url.Action("ExtratoPrint", "Extrato", new { contaCorrente = "paramContaCorrente", dataPesquisa = "paramDataPesquisa" }))';
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode concatenar os valores, algo parecido com isso:

```
var conta = "3cb012d1-6ceb-436f-8a0f-22c713703804";
var dataPesquisa = "31/12/2009";
var url = '@Url.Action("ExtratoPrint", "Extrato")?contaCorrente=' + conta + '&dataPesquisa=' + dataPesquisa;
```

O resultado será isto:

```
/extrato/extratoprint?contaCorrente=3cb012d1-6ceb-436f-8a0f-22c713703804&dataPesquisa=31/12/2009
```